# inserting results of different queries of different tables into a new created table in Postgres via PGadmin4

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, pgadmin-4

So i have created a table with multiple columns to collect some information about a database

```
CREATE TABLE DATENBANKEN (

    ID serial,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    Erstellt timestamp,
    Datenbankgröße VARCHAR(20),
    "Collation" VARCHAR (20),
    Beschreibung VARCHAR (50) 
)
```

and with the following insert statement i was able to fill the rows with the desired information

```
INSERT INTO DATENBANKEN (id, name, Erstellt, Datenbankgröße, "Collation")
    SELECT pg_database.oid,
    pg_database.datname,
    (pg_stat_file('base/'||pg_database.oid ||'/PG_VERSION')).modification,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)),
    pg_database.datcollate datcollate from pg_database
```

[this is the results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfkjl.png)

all the values above were captured from on table (pg_database)

now the last value "Beschreibung" is located in another table named (pg_shdescription)

so in this case i had to make another insert statement specifically for the column "Beschreibung"

```
INSERT INTO DATENBANKEN (Beschreibung)
    select pg_shdescription.description from pg_shdescription
```

[as you can see the rows in the column "Beschreibung" were not inserted beside the first three rows as i expected, but were added as additional rows with no connection to the data above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCx93.png)

[this is the table pg_shdescription and as you can see, for every objoid there is a specific description. So 1 is "default template for new databases"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KbPy.png)

[so here the 4th row in the column "Beschreibung" should have been in the second row where the datacenter name "template 1 is"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CWLk.png)

what did i do wrong here or what is the best way to insert certain data from different tables into a new table that are still linked together?

I really appreciate your help, any help

i tried INNER JOIN in the statement, but it did not work

```
CREATE TABLE DATENBANKEN (

    ID serial,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    Erstellt timestamp,
    Datenbankgröße VARCHAR(20),
    "Collation" VARCHAR (20),
    Beschreibung VARCHAR (50)

)
```

```
INSERT INTO DATENBANKEN (id, name, Erstellt, Datenbankgröße, "Collation")
    SELECT pg_database.oid,
    pg_database.datname,
    (pg_stat_file('base/'||pg_database.oid ||'/PG_VERSION')).modification,
    pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)),
    pg_database.datcollate datcollate from pg_database
```

```
INSERT INTO DATENBANKEN (Beschreibung)
    select pg_shdescription.description from pg_shdescription
INNER JOIN on Datenbanken.id = pg_shdescription.objoid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should join the tables before you insert, else you need to `UPDATE  DATENbBANKEN and not` INSERT INTO`

```
INSERT INTO DATENBANKEN (id, name, Erstellt, Datenbankgröße, "Collation",Beschreibung )
    SELECT pg_database.oid,
       pg_database.datname,
       (pg_stat_file('base/'||pg_database.oid ||'/PG_VERSION')).modification,
       pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)),
       pg_database.datcollate datcollate,
      pg_shdescription.description 
    from pg_database JOIN pg_shdescription
          ON pg_database.oid = pg_shdescription.objoid
```

Comment: thanks
i tried to join the tables as your suggested query but i get this error: 
ERROR: Column pg_database.id does not exist.
LINE 9: ON pg_database.id = pg_shdescription.objoid
although there is the column "id" in the created table "Beschreibung"

i also tried to update the table with:

UPDATE datenbanken 
SET beschreibung = (select pg_shdescription.description from pg_shdescription)

but it gave me this error:

ERROR: subquery used as expression resulted in more than one row

What is the problem I am doing here with these queries? I can't quite get my head around it.

Comment: Your column is pg_database.oid I changed the query acpurfongly

Comment: OK it did work  thanks to you, really appreciate it
i also wanted to do the same and join another table to get the backup time and add it to the column "Backup", but it is not working
here is what i did
pg_shdescription.description
pga_joblog.jlgstart
from pg_database LEFT JOIN pg_shdescription
ON pg_database.oid = pg_shdescription.objoid
LEFT JOIN pga_joblog
ON pg_shdescription.objoid = pga_joblog.jlgid
it says: Syntax error with ».«
pga_joblog.jigstart
i did exactly the same as you did. is there any thing more to it to get it working or do i have to do it in another way?